# Añadir elemento a cola vacía en C

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos

Tengo estas 3 funciones (insertar, eliminar y mostrar):

```
int colaInserta(Cola *c, tipoElemento elemento)
{

    tipoCelda *nuevo;   
    nuevo = (tipoCelda *)malloc(sizeof(tipoCelda));
    if(nuevo == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    nuevo->elemento = elemento;
    nuevo->sig = NULL;

    if(colaVacia(c) == 0)
    {
        c->frente = nuevo;
        c->fondo = nuevo;
    }
    else
    {
        c->fondo->sig = nuevo;
        c->fondo = nuevo;
    }   
    return 0;
}


int colaSuprime(Cola *c)
{

    tipoCelda *aBorrar;
    tipoElemento valor;

    if(colaVacia(c)!=0)
    {
        aBorrar = c->frente->sig;
        c->frente->sig = aBorrar->sig;
        valor = aBorrar->elemento;
        free(aBorrar);
        return valor;
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}

int recorrerCola(Cola *c)
{

    tipoCelda *p;
    p = c->frente->sig;

    while(p != NULL)    
    {
        printf("%d  ", p->elemento);
        p = p->sig;
    }   
}
```

El problema viene cuando ejecuto el main: Añado 1 elemento, lo elimino, y al volver a añadir otro elemento, la función mostrar no añade nada en ese caso. No se si es porque puede que la función suprime tiene que saber si el elemento que va a eliminar va a ser el ultimo o no, para dejar frente y fondo a null.

Comment: parece que vas a borrar el segundo elemento con esta instrucción: `aBorrar = c->frente->sig;`. ¿No sería más lógico borrar el frente? Te indico las dos líneas siguientes: `aBorrar = c->frente; c->frente = aBorrar->sig;`

Comment: Pues has dado en el clavo, tenia mal esas 2 lineas de código. Mil gracias.

Comment: Esta vez hubo suerte! ;)

Comment: Personalmente pienso que para ayudarte hace falta información, tal como la definición de `Cola` o `tipoCelda`.

Comment: @DavidIsla considera escribir una respuesta con la solución para que la pregunta pueda darse por solucionada

Answer (score 0):

Estás eliminando el segundo elemento de la cola, en lugar del primero. Si te fijas en esta instrucción:

```
aBorrar = c->frente->sig;
```

Estás asignando el objeto siguiente al frente (es decir, el segundo). Para solucionarlo, simplemente borra el frente y coloca como nuevo frente el segundo elemento. Se solucionaría con la siguiente modificación en tu función `colaSuprime`:

```
int colaSuprime(Cola *c)
{

    tipoCelda *aBorrar;
    tipoElemento valor;

    if(colaVacia(c)!=0)
    {
        aBorrar = c->frente;      // <- Borrarás el Frente
        c->frente = aBorrar->sig; // <- El nuevo frente, será el siguiente
        valor = aBorrar->elemento;
        free(aBorrar);
        return valor;
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Espero te ayude, un saludo.